# How can I find available network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, devices, systemd, udev

This is in regard to linux, but if anyone knows of a general *nix method that would be good.

I booted a system yesterday with an ethernet cable plugged in. "NetworkManager" is not installed, so once it started I went to look for the name of the ethernet interface with `ifconfig` to start a DHCP client manually, but it did not show anything other than `lo`.

The NIC was listed via `lspci`, and the appropriate kernel driver was loaded.  The system normally uses wifi, and I could remember the interface name for that was `wlan0`.  When I tried `ifconfig wlan0 up`, `wlan0` appeared.  But the only ethernet interface names I could remember were `eth[N]` and `em[N]` -- neither of which worked.

[This document](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) refers to "predictable interface names" but does not do a good job of explaining what they might be in simple terms.  It does refer to a piece of source code which implies the name in this case might be deduced from the the PCI bus and slot numbers, which seems like an unnecessarily complicated hassle.

Other searching around led me to believe that this might be determined by `systemd` in conjunction with `udev`, but there are almost 100 files in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` and spending an hour trying to determine where (and *if*) there's a systemd config file for this also seems ridiculous.

It would also be nice to know for certain that they are available, not just how they might be named *if* they are, so I can rule out hardware problems, etc. **Isn't there a simple way to find the names of available network interfaces on linux?**

Comment: In the question you state that you used `ip link` but then you accept an answer that suggests `ip link show` which does the exactly same thing. Why?

Comment: The manual pages for *iproute2* are quite good nowadays, I guess you're using and older version of the package.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The simplest method I know to list all of your interfaces is

```
ifconfig -a
```

**EDIT**

If you're on a system where that has been made obsolete, you can use

```
ip link show
```

Comment: If I'd just looked at the man page!  Be interesting to know if `ip` has a parallel, since supposedly ifconfig is being "obsoleted" in favour of that (IMO) more obtuse and less user friendly command.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I haven't heard that. Are you sure? The commands serve different purposes.  ip - show / manipulate routing, devices, policy routing and tunnels and ifconfig - configure a network interface

Comment: First thing in my `man ifconfig`: "NOTE This program is obsolete!  For replacement check ip..." That may be specific to linux.  Hopefully they have to retain it for backward compatibility with something.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I'm on 12.04 ubuntu. Things do change from time to time. Try `ip link show`

Comment: :) That works too.  You should edit it into the answer to illustrate the parallel with ifconfig.

Comment: ifconfig has been deprecated, TMK, so we should be trying to show examples using `ip`. See the ifconfig wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig.

Comment: @slm Although the question is (was) linux specific, an example using *both* seems good as BSD users may be in the habit of looking at "linux" pages anyway -- in fact I'll take linux out of the title and edit a bit (originally this was self-answered and I did not think there was a portable method).

Comment: ifconfig deprecated? come on. This command has been around for like 30 years.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - It is according to the Wikipedia page and other sources if you google it. I'm not the one deprecating it, so don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - if it wasn't tagged linux I wouldn't have said anything but we have a lot of back catalog that shows `ifconfig` and we should be nudging ppl to getting more comfortable w/ `ip` going forward. If the intent was unix and not linux per-say then I'll remove the comments if someone who's sure wants to retag it. BTW, I think your A is better 8-)

Comment: `ifcconfig ` can (and likely will) remain deprecated for quite some time, and even if removed from the base system - I would expect it to be available from the repo (or at least a PPA).

Comment: use `ip l` if you want to save some chars there.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez Nevertheless if you had checked `ifconfig(8)` you'd know why it is. See the NOTES and BUGS section for starters.

Comment: @Pryftan I'll check that out

Comment: @MichaelMartinez I might also add that technically `netstat` is also considered deprecated iirc. Instead one should use `ss`. But then that's Linux; I've not really used BSD or any other Unix in years but I have this vague thought that BSD does have `netstat`!

Comment: For physical NIC, you can use

`find /sys/class/net/*/device`

Answer (score 90):

The kernel lists them by name in `/sys`, both separately in (e.g.) the tree of PCI devices -- although finding them there if you don't know where they are to start with is not simple -- and together via symlinks in `/sys/class/net`. E.g.:

```
> ls /sys/class/net
em1 lo wlp6so
```

Another example:

```
> ls /sys/class/net
lo p6s1 wlan0
```

If you are not sure which is which, you could just put them all up with either:

```
ifconfig [name] up
```

Or:

```
ip link set [name] up
```

And then look at the (fairly clear) clues listed by `ifconfig` (with no arguments).   The systemd source code linked from the Freedesktop.org document also refers to:

```
Two character prefixes based on the type of interface:
 *   en -- ethernet
 *   sl -- serial line IP (slip)
 *   wl -- wlan
 *   ww -- wwan
```

Although in one of the cases above (`p6s1`) there is no prefix.

Comment: The prefix I get for ethernet is `eth`. I believe `en` is for wireless lan.

Comment: @kaushalmodi `eth` is a linux kernel thing; systemd implements via udev Freedesktop.org's *predictable* interface names -- the kernel ones are not predictable in the same sense, which is the cause of all the confusion.  The quote above is explicitly cut n' pasted [from here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#n20).  There's more to it than that, since I don't have any systemd machines using `en` for ethernet; the closest is `em`, others are completely different.  You can read the Freedesk.org link in the question yourself for more explanation.

Comment: [Later] Sometime in the past year Fedora or systemd corrected that?  My PCI ethernet is now `eno1`.

Comment: @goldilocks &c: you can override that by the kernel command line options: *`biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0`*. I never found the systemd way 'predictable' and eth as a prefix seemed reasonable to me so I have always had that. Anyway there it is: you can have it the pseudo-random way (i.e. systemd) or the other way depending on kernel options.

Answer (score 13):

I always do `cat /proc/net/dev` it's simple and easy to memorize

Comment: but that only gives active interfaces, not all the interfaces

Answer (score 6):

`ifconfig` = Solaris
`ipconfig` = Windows
`ip` = Linux

That I know, but am certainly open to additions and corrections.

Comment: Huh? ifconfig is Linux also.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Read the first paragraph (after the synopsis) of `man ifconfig` on a linux system.

Comment: @fpmurphy `ifconfig(8)` is also deprecated under Linux. Please see the sections NOTES and BUGS. This has been the case for years now. So although `ifconfig` works under Linux it's not the correct way.

Comment: @Pryftan.  Just because a utility is depreciated, does not mean that the utility does not work for your requirements.  Correct way?  Sorry but Linux does not mandate correct ways.

Comment: @fpmurphy For some uses however it does not work. Yes it can work but using deprecated ways is - for many cases - just silly. Why would anyone want to use the old way that for all you know could be removed in the future? It's been deprecated for many many years now! Anyway for `ifconfig` what's the point of using it? `ip` is more than sufficient. But hey if you like it so be it. I'm just saying that there are reasons it's deprecated!

Comment: @fpmurphy you're right, "correct" is the wrong word. "Officially supported" is a better way to express it. For a number of people, community / enterprise support is very important. If it's not important to you, then you keep doing your thing. Some distros have already stopped including the utility, and I imagine as time goes by it'll be more and more difficult to install and use the ifconfig utility (esp. once they stop building packages completely). But it's open source, so as long as the Linux API remains compatible, keep on keeping on - just expect it to take more work over time.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no `ifconfig`, `ip` available in the system one way that helped me getting IP address on Ubuntu was:

```
hostname -i
```

As pointed out in the comments, this mechanism relies on DNS hostname reolution and will not provide authorative results for all available network interfaces.

Still, this command might be helpful in troubleshooting scenarios with containers (Docker, LXC), where system tools are often not available. And at least in some cases it shows container IP which might be helpful depending on your goal.

Comment: Probably not a great methodology as this is done via DNS resolution and on systems with hostname `localhost` (eg., likely most PC users), it will yield 127.0.0.1.  None the less may be useful on whatever oddball system it is that doesn't have `[/usr]/sbin/ip`.

Comment: I thought that as well. But in fact in my containers I'm getting their IP in that way.
I think, in some cases that command may be useful.

Comment: Makes sense -- I didn't think of that.  You might want to edit details into the answer for people who's search terms include (eg) `docker` or `lxc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ip -br a
```

short and easy to remember thanks to a silly clothing mnemonic.

prints something like:

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp0s32f6        DOWN           
wlp0s10f3        UP             192.168.3.144/24 ge80::f074:13c4:50e1:41a8/64 
docker1          DOWN           172.17.3.1/16
```